# Pagination not working properly

Tags: php, theme-development, loop, pagination

I have a list of posts from a category as seen [here in this example](http://adambalan.com/WordPressDev/category/uncategorized). The problem is, if you scroll down to the bottom and click older, you'll see that the posts on the page have not changed at all, how ever the url has changed.

Can some one tell me whats wrong with the following code that generate this?

```
function category_query($query){
    if(is_admin || !$query->is_main_query()){
        return;
    }

    if(is_category()){
        $cat_id = get_cat_ID( single_cat_title(null, false) );
        $query->set("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=10" );
        return;
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','category_query');

$attr = array(
    'align' => 'left',
    'class' => 'thumbnail imageRight',
    'width' => 350,
    'height' => 350
);
if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="post"><?php
        the_post_thumbnail('medium', $attr); ?>
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;

    ?>
    <ul class="pager paddingBottom20">
      <li class="previous">
        <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries'); ?>
      </li>
      <li class="next">
        <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;'); ?>
      </li>
    </ul><?php 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `query_posts` in the template. If you delete that line, your template will paginate correctly.

If you want to alter the main query, use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action.

Currently, your query overwrites the default main query, and you don't set any pagination parameters within the query, so you're always going to get the first 10 posts.